# VM Won't boot due to being unable to lock the attached disks

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, vmware

First time posting here and by no means a vmware expert but am pretty proficient

A few days ago a client of our host needed to be shut down in a hurry for an emergency power outage. We were able to go onto each guest and quickly shut them down and confirm they did so then were able to shut the host downs but were not able to take a clone of them before hand so we don't have a quick fix to get to right before the shut down other then hopefully recovering the existing vmdk's.

After rebooting the hosts all the server's came online other than one - the main DC. This is also the server one of the file shares lives on which is what we care most about. Initially the error we got was that it couldn't boot the machine due to not being able to find the vmdk's associated with the second and third disk, 0001.vmdk and 0002.vmdk. If we booted the base vmdk without the disk's it booted just fine but as soon as we attached the other disks we got the error they couldn't be found. We confirmed the files were in fact present but had an altered name. For example instead of being Maybelline.vmdk they were Mwybelline.vmdk. The folder names were still correct. We followed some other forum posts with similar issues to start a new VM and point to the existing disks to correct the mapping issue. After doing that we started to get a new error that the CID's were no longer matching - followed a guide to correct that and moved onto a new error which is the one i am currently stumped on. When going to boot the machine it gets to 95 percent complete then fails to boot because it fails to lock 0001.vmdk and 0002.vdmk. I have checked and there are no .lck files and i have confirmed the file is in lock mode 0 using ssh (the mac address where the device with the lock was a 0's as well). I have checked the descriptor and all the info is correct and i attempted to refresh the vmx which didnt seem to help and all the info seemed correct within

i am in the process of moving copies of the vmdk's in question to a new host to see if that helps but wanted to reach out here as its a slow process i have little faith in

Oh yeah sorry this is on ESXi 5.1

Thanks in advance for any input you would be a life saver!